# Lotus out of office function doesn't work correctly

Tags: function, lotus, agent

after upgrading template from dwa7 to mail85 the out of office function doesn't work anymore, when i send an e-mail to user@domain the message is delivered but the automatic response from out of office doesn't work. The function only works with the agent, but 6 in 6 hours, not immediately. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article: [The IBM Lotus Notes and Domino Out of Office service: Best practices](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/01072009040728PMWEBSS8.htm). The article contains several things to check in order to ensure that you can get the Out of Office Service to run instead of the Out of Office Agent.